# How can I synchronize the access to a resource across all the request to a web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redis, asp.net-core-webapi

It is an web api, which access some resource with an access token in the sever side. The token expires after 180 seconds. A request will initially generate the token from the token endpoint and stores it in a Redis cache and that action is followed by a subsequent call using that token. There is a check for the token expiration and when a request finds it expired then it will get a new access token and update it in the cache.

The problem is that if two requests find that the token is expired and let just say that the 1st request gets a new token - `abc123` and updates it but for the 2nd request it has already checked that the token was expired and now this will also get a new token - `xyz321` and replaces the `abc123` with the `xyz321`. But for the 1st request the token `abc123` is no longer valid so the subsequent call will just fail with the token `abc123`.

So this is something what I tried to prevent this issue:

```
public async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync()
{
    string token = string.Empty;
    using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false))
    {
        try
        {
            if (_storage.IsTokenExpired()) // returns "false" if expired or no token set
            {
                mutex.WaitOne();
                if (_storage.IsTokenExpired())
                {
                    token = await AccessTokenEndpointCallAsync();
                    _storage.StoreAccessToken(token);
                }
                else
                {
                    token = _storage.ReadAccessToken();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                token = _storage.ReadAccessToken();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }
    return token;
}
```

Well if I start a browser and make a call to the api it all works but then if I open another browser and make a call it throws the error -

> Message: Object synchronization method was called from an
> unsynchronized block of code.   StackTrace:    at
> System.Threading.Mutex.ReleaseMutex()

Comment: Use a static `SemaphoreSlim` That allows you to lock async methods,

Answer (score -1):

If you have only one web server, you can simply use `lock()` on a lock object.  Forget the mutex.  Note, however, that you cannot await inside a locking context.  Your locked block will have to be synchronous.

To answer your question, you are releasing a mutex you did not acquire.  To acquire the mutext you must first wait for it.  See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?view=net-6.0).